# How do you a double factorial in python?

Tags: python, math, factorial

I've been stucked on this question for a really long time.
I've managed to do a single recursive factorial.

```
def factorial(n):
     if n == 0:
         return 1
     else:
         return n * factorial(n-1)
```

Double factorial
For an even integer n, the double factorial is the product of all even positive integers less than or equal to n. For an odd integer p, the double factorial is the product of all odd positive integers less than or equal to p.

If n is even, then `n!! = n*(n - 2)*(n - 4)*(n - 6)* ... *4*2`

If p is odd, then `p!! = p*(p - 2)*(p - 4)*(p - 6)* ... *3*1`

But I have no idea to do a double factorial. Any help?

Comment: Look at what changes between the two: the `n-1` becomes `n-2` and the final number (bases case) changes from 0 to one of 2 or 1.

Answer (score 19):

```py
from functools import reduce # only in Python 3

reduce(int.__mul__, range(n, 0, -2))
```

Comment: Wait, this gets actually upvoted? At least use `operator.mul` (somewhat cleaner, as you don't type underscores, and is "type-agnostic"). And I for one would prefer the explicitly iterative version anyway, if I was to avoid stack overflows (and mentioned below, that's *not* the point of most factorial assignments).

Comment: Also the point of any factorial function is to teach people recursion, not actually being efficient. And you'll find xrange is even more efficient. ;)

Comment: @delnan: Since `range` only yields `int`, using `int.__mul__` is alright(And don't have to do another importing). @Lennart Regebro: True. However I wrote this code in Python 3. As for the recursion usage, don't you think the the `reduce` can be considered as a recursion function? Understanding it could be a help.

Comment: `reduce(long.__mul__,range(n,0,-2),1L)` avoids problem when the product gets too big

Comment: This is considered obfuscated python? Wow. It looks pretty normal to me, its just a standard fold, just like I'd use in Haskell or Lisp.

Answer (score 5):

Isn't that just the same as the factorial with a different ending condition and a different parameter to the recursion call?

```
def doublefactorial(n):
     if n <= 0:
         return 1
     else:
         return n * doublefactorial(n-2)
```

If `n` is even, then it will halt when `n == 0`. If `n` is odd, then it will halt when `n == -1`.

Comment: You'll want to call doublefactorial in the recursive call. Made the same mistake.

Comment: You can halt at 1 instead of -1. I know, minimal improvement, but still. :)

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that the double factorial is defined for negative real numbers (-1)!! = 1, (-3)!! = -1 (even negative integers (such -2, -4, ...) should have solution as +/- inf) so... something is smelling bad in all solutions for negative numbers. If one want to define the double factorial for al reals those solutions don't work. The solution is to define the double factorial using gamma function.

```
import scipy.special as sp
from numpy import pi

def dfact(x):
    n = (x + 1.)/2.
    return 2.**n * sp.gamma(n + 0.5)/(pi**(0.5))
```

It works! :D

Comment: That's for odd x only, right?

Answer (score 3):

Starting `Python 3.8`, we can use the [`prod`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html#math.prod) function from the [`math`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html) module which calculates the product of all elements in an iterable, which in our case is `range(n, 0, -2)`:

```
import math

math.prod(range(n, 0, -2))
```

Note that this also handles the case `n = 0` in which case the result is `1`.

Answer (score 1):

My version of the recursive solution, in one line:

```
dfact = lambda n: (n <= 0) or n * dfact(n-2)
```

However, it is also interesting to note that the double factorial can be expressed in terms of the "normal" factorial. For odd numbers,

n!! = (2*k)! / (2**k * k!)

where k = (n+1)/2. For even arguments n=2k, although this is not consistent with a generalization to complex arguments, the expression is simpler,

n!! = (2k)!! = 2*k * k!.

All this means that you can write code using the factorial function from the standard math library, which is always nice:

```
import math
fact = math.factorial
def dfact(n):
  if n % 2 == 1:
    k = (n+1)/2
    return fact(2*k) / (2**k * fact(k))
  else:
    return 2**k * fact(k)
```

Now, this code is obviously not very efficient for large n, but it is quite instructive. More importantly, since we are dealing with standard factorials now, it is a very good starting point for optimizations when dealing with really large numbers. You try to use logarithms or gamma functions to get approximate double factorials for large numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
def doublefactorial(n):
     if n <= 0:
         return 1
     else:
         return n * doublefactorial(n-2)
```

That should do it. Unless I'm misunderstanding

Comment: Why are you returning 2 for n == 0? it should be 1, just use `if n <= 1: return 1`, though really it should be `if n < 0: scream loudly if n in (0, 1): return 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
def doublefactorial(n):
     if n in (0, 1):
         return 1
     else:
         return n * doublefactorial(n-2)
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand it correctly, but will this work

```
 def factorial(n):
 if n == 0 or n == 1:
     return 1
 else:
     return n * factorial(n-2)
```

Comment: Not quite. You need to adjust the base case, otherwise it doesn't terminate for odd numbers.

Comment: You'd need to stop at less then 0 otherwise an odd value will go into an infinite loop (or eventually hit a stackoverflow)

Answer (score 0):

```
def double_fact(number):
    if number==0 or number==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return number*double_fact(number-2)
```

I think this should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

`reduce(lambda x,y: y*x, range(n,1,-2))`

Which is basically the same as the simple iterative version:

```
x = n
for y in range(n-2, 1, -2):
    x*=y
```

Obviously you can also do it recursively, but what's the point ? This kind of example implemented using recursivity are fine when using all recursive languages, but with imperative language it's always making simple tools like recursivity looking more complex than necessary, while recursivity can be a real simplifier when dealing with fundamentally recursive structures like trees.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, I decided like this:

```
def double_factorial(N):
if N == 0: return 1
elif N == 1: return 1
elif N == 2: return 2
else:
    return N * double_factorial(N - 2)
```